# "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_add_number", referenced from: (C)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

In macOS With Visual Studio Code, I tried to compile C source code.
(There are 3 parts of source code bellow)

**head.h(edited)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int add_number(int a, int b);
```

**body.c**

```
#include "head.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int add_number(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "head.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int result = add_number (1, 2);
    printf("%d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

AND

`gcc main.c`

However, when I pushed F5 to compile this c code,
following error occured:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_add_number", referenced from:
      _main in main-49215f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is it link fail messages?
Is anyone help me to fix this errors?
 for example, vsc setting or ...

P.S.
my vsc's tasks.json is as bellow:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "gcc build",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": 
            { 
                "fileLocation": [ 
                "relative", "${workspaceRoot}" 
                ], 
                "pattern": 
                { 
                    // The regular expression. 
                    //Example to match: helloWorld.c:5:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'prinft' 
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning error):\\s+(.*)$", 
                    "file": 1, 
                    "line": 2, 
                    "column": 3, 
                    "severity": 4, 
                    "message": 5 
                }
            },
        "group": "build"
        },
    {
        "label": "execute", 
        "command": "cd ${fileDirname} && ./${fileBasenameNoExtension}", 
        "group": "test"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Define the function add_number. What is unclear?

Comment: You need to add the C source file (or the library) where you define that function to your project.

Comment: Do you have a definition (implementation) of an `add_number` function somewhere? Where? In another source file? Then you need to build with that source file as well, so they will be linked together into the final executable program.

Comment: Thanks guys, for your comments I added my souce codes. There are header file + c body file + main c file.

Comment: Maybe ``head.c`` should be called ``head.h``

Comment: As I suspected. You need to build both `body.c` and `main.c`, as in `gcc main.c body.c`.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. Head file name is fixed. And I tried to build both of them @Someprogrammerdude thanks!

Comment: The two source file needs to be built *together*, and *at the same time*. As (again) `gcc main.c body.c`. The command you show only builds `main.c`. Please show us the build configuration.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you mean vsc's biuld configuration?? tasks.json is as bellow:

Comment: That shown configuration will only build the *current* file in the editor, not both files together. I recommend that you start learning about `make` and makefiles, for one way to build multi-file projects. You could also use other tools such as [CMake](https://cmake.org/) (and many others) to auto-generate build configurations and makefiles which can then be handled by your build task.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's an error from the linker.  The reason is that you built your application by means of

> gcc main.c

which has a declaration of `add_number` (from head.h), but no definition because the module / compilation unit which implements that function is missing.  A quick fix is to

> gcc body.c main.c

Comment: Thanks a lot. And another question it is. Is it a solution what I found that?  >>> head.h `inline int add_number(int a, int b);`  head.c `int add_number(int a, int b);` main.c `external add_number(int a, int b);` .  <-- exclude other souces.

Comment: I answered this one in a separate answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59892960/1556746) because of the length restriction in comments.

Answer (score 1):

When you

`inline int add_number(int a, int b); // head.h`

`int add_number(int a, int b) { ... } // head.c`

`extern int add_number(int a, int b); // main.c`

Then the problem is still the same:  The code works because there is an implementation of `add_number` provided you compile like in the other answer, i.e. with

> gcc body.c main.c

If you return to your previous compile that did only

> gcc main.c

then the implementation of `add_number` is still missing. If you want to have the function inline, then remove the implementation from `head.c` and do it in `head.h` like so:

```
static inline int add_number (int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

and remove the prototype from `main.c` (in general it is a bad idea to have `external` declarations in C-modules, they should go to the headers so that all modules including the header agree on the prototype).

In your special case, after moving `add_number` from `head.c` to an inline function in `head.h`, the C file will be empty so that

> gcc main.c

Works as expected.

Comment: @M.M: Yes.  As I wrote in an other comment: "I answered this one in a separate answer (stackoverflow.com/a/59892960/1556746) because of the length restriction in comments."

Comment: the Answer should answer what's posted in the Question   . It would be better to make a new question (either OP can or you can make one based on their comment)